# How to fetch google analytics data api GA4 in .net core?

Tags: c#

```
        var request = new RunReportRequest
    {
        Property = $"properties/{_settings.GoogleAnalytics.PropertyId}",
        Dimensions = {new Dimension {Name = "eventName"}, new Dimension {Name = "customEvent:event_category" } },
        DimensionFilter = click,
        Metrics = {new Metric {Name = "eventCount"}},
        DateRanges =
        {
            new DateRange
                {StartDate = startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), EndDate = endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}
        }
    };

    var response = await _analyticsClient.GetClient().RunReportAsync(request);
```

I'm using .NET core and the nuget package Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta to query Google Analytics.I have doubt on how to get response.I have searched a lot but cant able to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the exact same problem. Please make sure to install the **latest pre-release build**. (as natively the latest build doesn't come with the required methods and return types as stated in all of the tutorials online regarding .NET.. go figure..)

Steps:

1. Nuget Package Manager
2. Go to installed packages **(tick the show
   pre-release checkbox)**
3. Select your package.
4. Update Accordingly

[image: Screenshot of nuget package manager for build]